# ANTLR4 C++ listener not calling overriden enterRule methods

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I need some help with walking a tree with a listener (using C++). After initiating the tree walk with my listener and using gdb to attach to the process (I built the C++ runtime library with the Debug flag to be able to have the debug info in gdb), I can see it enters `ParseTreeWalker::walk()`, and if I execute `getText()` on the `ParseTree*` parameter I can see it has all the tokens from my input, so far so good. But when `walk()` calls `enterRule()`:

```
void ParseTreeWalker::enterRule(ParseTreeListener *listener, ParseTree *r) const {
  auto *ctx = downCast<ParserRuleContext*>(r);
  listener->enterEveryRule(ctx);
  ctx->enterRule(listener);
}
```

When I try to step in `ctx->enterRule(listener)` it just goes back to `walk()`. I've added breakpoints to my listener methods I want to debug but it appears they're not being called. I even added some std::cout statements in them but I don't see them being executed. I also added some std::cout statements to my overriden version of `visitTerminal` and those are getting printed...

If I inspect the `ctx` variable inside this method, it does seem to have the right type

```
_vptr.ParseTree = 0x6e6048 <vtable for MyParser::DocumentContext+16>...
```

So, I'm very confused, am I missing something obvious that's causing my enter* methods not get executed?

---

The generated BaseListener looks like this:

```
#include "antlr4-runtime.h"
#include "MyDCXParserListener.h"

class  MyDCXParserBaseListener : public MyDCXParserListener {
public:

  virtual void enterDocument(MyDCXParser::DocumentContext * /*ctx*/) override { }
  virtual void exitDocument(MyDCXParser::DocumentContext * /*ctx*/) override { }

  virtual void enterLine(MyDCXParser::LineContext * /*ctx*/) override { }
  virtual void exitLine(MyDCXParser::LineContext * /*ctx*/) override { }
    
  virtual void enterEveryRule(antlr4::ParserRuleContext * /*ctx*/) override { }
  virtual void exitEveryRule(antlr4::ParserRuleContext * /*ctx*/) override { }
  virtual void visitTerminal(antlr4::tree::TerminalNode * /*node*/) override { }
  virtual void visitErrorNode(antlr4::tree::ErrorNode * /*node*/) override { }
};
```

The derived class I created looks like this:

`.h`

```
#include "antlr4-runtime.h"
#include "MyDCXParser.h"
#include "MyDCXParserBaseListener.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyDCXListener : public MyDCXParserBaseListener
{
private:
public:

    //
    MyDCXListener();

    //
    ~MyDCXListener();

    // Don't allow copy constructor nor assignment operator
    MyDCXListener(const MyDCXListener&) = delete;
    MyDCXListener& operator=(const MyDCXListener&) = delete;

    //
    void enterDocument(MyDCXParser::DocumentContext * /*ctx*/) override;
    void exitDocument(MyDCXParser::DocumentContext * /*ctx*/) override {}

    void enterLine(MyDCXParser::LineContext * /*ctx*/) override;
    void exitLine(MyDCXParser::LineContext * /*ctx*/) override {}
    
    void visitTerminal(antlr4::tree::TerminalNode *node) override { std::cout << "visitTerminal(): '" << node->getText().c_str() << std::endl; }
};
```

`.cpp`

```
#include "MyDCXListener.h"

//
MyDCXListener::MyDCXListener()
{
}

MyDCXListener::~MyDCXListener()
{
}

void MyDCXListener::enterDocument(MyDCXParser::DocumentContext * ctx)
{
    std::cout << "MyDCXListener::enterDocument()" << std::endl; 
}

void MyDCXListener::enterLine(MyDCXParser::LineContext * ctx)
{
    std::cout << "MyDCXListener::enterLine()" << std::endl; 
}
```

I see the "visitTerminal" message but not the ones for enterDocument() nor enterLine()

Comment: Are you overriding ["ParseTreeListener::enterEveryRule(ctx);"](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/aa1f1f12a846846fcb78544bdb2ad135471376db/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/tree/ParseTreeListener.h#L30), or are you overriding ["ParserRuleContext::enterRule()"](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/aa1f1f12a846846fcb78544bdb2ad135471376db/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/ParserRuleContext.h#L80)? For most, when we say "we wrote a listener", we are subclassing from "ParseTreeListener" and overriding "enterEveryRule()", not "enterRule()" because that doesn't existing for ParseTreeListener.

Comment: I didn't override `ParseTreeListener::enterEveryRule(ctx);`, but from the generated `MyParserBaseListener` class I have overriden `enter*` methods such as `virtual void enterDocument(MyParser::DocumentContext * /*ctx*/) override { }` and `virtual void visitTerminal(antlr4::tree::TerminalNode * /*node*/) override { }`. And `visitTerminal` is getting called, but not the `enter*` methods.

Comment: Unless we see your code, we can't solve this.

Comment: Edited the question to add the code :D

Comment: For the partial code you give, it looks okay. I'm not sure what is going on. I took the [abb grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/abb), generated a driver, and modified it to call a listener with a couple of overrides. It works fine. https://github.com/kaby76/so73884939

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out what was wrong. I was trying to code too much without testing first. I wanted to try both a listener and a visitor. I made 2 calls to the antlr4 tool, first one with "-listener" param, but the second one had "-visitor -no-listener".... so that second call modified my generated parser cpp file to not have calls to listener overriden methods... since the visitTerminal( ) is also used by the visitor, I didn't think of checking this first...